# UITableView paging Load More from the server iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am looking to load results from the server for UITableView while I have that implemented, I want to enable paging for those results.

Does anyone know any article that will explain me this or can someone explain here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an article but it may help you: [Paging / Pagination / Load More... from a UITableView](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/18876-paging-pagination-load-more-uitableview.html)

Comment: Yes I already seen that, but it doesn't help that much. Is there anything else out there?